# how to make xmonad ignore the right alt key in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xmonad

How can I get xmonad to match the left alt key and not the right alt key?
Ubuntu binds these both to mod1 in xmodmap.

Answer (score 1):

You can look which keys are the mod keys with "**xmodmap -pm**". xmodmap also allows to change the mod key configuration. Just enter the apropiate keycodes into ~/.Xmodmap or ~/.xmodmaprc

To find out which keycode the right alt key emits start "xev" like this:

```
xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\)
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure about alt, but the xmonad [config archive](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Config_archive#Minimal_xmonad_config_files) has an example that uses Super *instead of* alt:

```
import XMonad

main = xmonad defaultConfig
        { modMask = mod4Mask -- Use Super instead of Alt
        , terminal = "urxvt"
        -- more changes
        }
```

You'll need to compile the new config file, so you'll need [haskell](http://haskell.org/) if you don't have it already.

Comment: i played with doing this and then swapping the l-alt and win keys, did'nt work out well. I am currently using the win key and its a stretch for my fingers to reach.

Comment: Your win key is not on the left?

Comment: it to the left of the left alt key. just too far away for my fingers to reach comfortabley